# Prove that $f(x)=0$ for any $x\in[0,1]$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ a function such that $f(x)\leq2\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$. Prove that $f(x)=0$ for any $x\in[0,1]$. 
$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\Rightarrow\frac{F(x)}{F'(x)}\geq2 \Rightarrow (lnF(x))'\geq 2$, $x\in[0,1]$ $ \Rightarrow F(x) \geq e^{2x} $. But this is false for $x=0$ if $f(x)$ is not $0$. Is this a consistent proof?

Comment: What do you mean by $\implies e^{2x}$?

Comment: You do want to assume $f$ is continuous if you're going to talk about $F'(x)$.

Comment: It's very unclear, let alone being consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-2x}F(x)) = -2e^{-2x}F(x) + e^{-2x}F'(x)\le 0.$$